# On Merge Request: Show pipeline state of branch

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a simple Gitlab ci pipeline that runs some tests and linting on every commit to show the health of the branch.
I recently added a new job I only want to run on merge requests. Therefore I added

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```

to that specific job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

This results in a detached pipeline with only this job, what is theoretically fine.

Unfortunately now I don't see the state of the normal pipeline anymore in the Merge Request review page, but only the state of the detached pipeline.

Is there a way to see the results of both pipelines at the same time in the Merge Request review page?

Comment: Have you figured this out?